# Spring GemFire client authentication

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

I have implemented a clustered environment with a GemFire cache in *Spring*, using cache-server and client-cache. How can I implement authentication or any kind of security between client and server in a clustered environment?

Answer (score 1):

@Sonal-

Several different ways!  Have a look at...

https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/apache-geode/security-example/src/test/java/example/app/geode/security/GeodeSecurityIntegrationTests.java

While this is coded for *Apache Geode*, it applies equally to **Pivotal GemFire 9.x** (which is based on *Apache Geode* **1.0.0-incubating**).

You can also read [my Spring.io Blog Post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/10/spring-data-geode-1-0-0-incubating-release-released), which specifically covered **Security**.  While this pertained to Spring Data for Apache Geode, it equally applies in *Spring Data GemFire* **2.0.0**, which is based on *Pivotal GemFire* **9.0.x**.

Hope this helps!

-John